# Prolog returns variable name instead of value

Tags: prolog

I have a method which checks where to place the next brick while building a tower.

```
freePosition(POS, LEVEL) :- levelWithSpace(LEVEL),
                            freePositionOnLevel(POS, LEVEL).
```

This method checks for a level with space and asks for the free positions on this level.
In my case it should return two results:

- POS=1, LEVEL=2
- POS=2, LEVEL=2

However it returns the following output:

```
?- freePosition(POS, LEVEL).
POS = 1,
LEVEL = 2 ;
POS = LEVEL, LEVEL = 2 ;
```

How can I change the behavior that it returns POS=2 instead of POS=LEVEL?

Comment: Why do you need the behavior to be different? Prolog isn't returning a value, it's telling you what instantiations of the variables make your query succeed. It happens that if `LEVEL = 2` (`LEVEL` is unified with 2) and `POS = LEVEL` (`POS` is unified with `LEVEL`) that your query succeeds. In Prolog, it's equivalent to `POS = 2` and `LEVEL = 2`, just represented differently.

Comment: As a related exercise, run `swipl` and, at the prompt, enter, `X = 2, Y = 2.`

Comment: I know that prolog works like that. After the execution i want to interpret the results in another program. So i don't want to add additional logic. Is there really no way to always return the values?

Comment: Are you talking about outputting the information to a file or `stdout` so that another Prolog program, or a program in a different language, can read it? Perhaps you could be a little more clear about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for being not clear enough. Yes I have another program (different language) which reads the prolog output from stdin/stdout. But I think the answer from "repeat" solves my problem.

Comment: Yes, @repeat has the answer which will output to `stdout`. Or, look at file I/O routines (and `format` has a form which outputs to a stream).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the builtin `format/2` to emit a formatted string:

```
?- freePosition(POS, LEVEL),
   format('Pos = ~d, Level = ~d~n', [POS,LEVEL]).
```

This will make it easy to get a uniform output style no matter what Prolog implementation you use.

Note that the concrete style of answers given by the Prolog interpreter top-level differs quite a bit between different Prolog implementations.